# What is stored in similarities.SparseMatrixSimilarity().index

Tags: gensim, cosine-similarity

I am using cosine similarity function in gensim module, which is similarities.SparseMatrixSimilarity(). And I want to get similarities between all index documents. The method have an attribute:index, but I don't know what are stored in it.

```
    sim = similarities.SparseMatrixSimilarity(
        self.tfidf_vectors, num_features=self.featurenum)
    sim.save(path + '/model/train_index.index')
    print(sim.index.shape)
    print(sim.index.toarray().shape)
```

len(self.tfidf.vectors) is 9117, but sim.index.shape is (9117, 143807) and sim.index.toarray().shape is also (9117, 143807). I guess it should be (9117,9117). What is in sim.index ?

Answer (score 0):

9117 is the count of documents and 143897 is the count of the words in all documents. So, index is a matrix and each row represents a document and each column represents a word.